# Domains not working - help with VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Gamer-Source.com is not showing up properly, it's showing Starcraft-Source.com instead of it's own site.  Can anyone point out any issues with the configuration below?

cdn.gamer-source.com is also not showing up.

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       spireprod
127.0.0.1       www.battle-report.com
127.0.0.1       www.gamer-source.com
127.0.0.1       cdn.gamer-source.com
127.0.0.1       www.seccbiblebowl.org //this domain works 100%
127.0.0.1       www.diablo-source.com
127.0.0.1       www.starcraft-source.com //this works as well
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/gamer-source.com**

```
<VirtualHost 64.253.105.250:80>
        ServerAdmin x@x.com
        DocumentRoot /home/source/public_html/
        ServerName www.gamer-source.com
        ServerAlias gamer-source.com
        ErrorLog /home/source/log/error_log
        TransferLog /home/source/log/access_log
</VirtualHost>
         <VirtualHost 64.253.105.250:80>
                  ServerName cdn.gamer-source.com
                  DocumentRoot /home/source/public_html/cdn/
         </VirtualHost>
         <VirtualHost 64.253.105.250:80>
                 ServerName img.gamer-source.com
                 DocumentRoot /home/source/public_html/img/
         </VirtualHost>

# ---------- Starcraft-Source.com -----------
<VirtualHost 64.253.105.250:80>
        ServerName www.starcraft-source.com
        ServerAlias starcraft-source.com
        DocumentRoot /home/source/public_html/starcraft-source/
</VirtualHost>
         <VirtualHost 64.253.105.250:80>
                 ServerName derwish.starcraft-source.com
                 DocumentRoot /home/source/public_html/derwish/
         </VirtualHost>

# ----------- Diablo-Source.com -------------
<VirtualHost 64.253.105.250:80>
        ServerName www.diablo-source.com
        ServerAlias diablo-source.com
        DocumentRoot /home/source/public_html/diablo-source/
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update**

This is very odd, I use VIM to modify these files.  All of the other site configuration files show the correct coloring, where words like "ServerAdmin" and "ServerAlias" are teal and various elements colored.  I don't see any syntaxual errors, what else could be causing that?

Comment: What else is present in sites-available?

Comment: Aside from the default, another configuration for another site that mirrors this configuration except for a different domain/path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the above config file enabled? Is it linked from /etc/apache2/sites-available/gamer-source.com to /etc/apache2/sites-**enabled**/gamer-source.com ? If it is, did you restart apache after enabeling it?

Do you have a NameVirtualHost directive somewhere in your apache config?

Comment: I do have NameVirtualHost within the ports configuration file for the IP that all of these sites are set to listen on.

Comment: @Webnet you haven't answered about the symlink though. You can force the symlink again with `a2ensite game-source.com`.

Comment: Doh!  You're right, I never did that.... dangit!

It's so easy to make a simple stupid mistake with all of this ^_^

Comment: @Webnet no problem, it's called experience. You gain it by doing things wrong a lot, don't ask ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, its probably because apache differentiates between your external IP and your internal IP; from the [VirtualHost page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#ip) (see page for their example apache conf):

> Requests for any address not specified
>   in one of the  directives
>   (such as localhost, for example) will
>   go to the main server, if there is
>   one.

You may want to set your hosts file to have the domains use the appropriate IP.

Comment: I adjusted /etc/hosts to have the actual IP that the domains are listening on and it had no effect.

Comment: Did you restart networking once you made those changes?

Comment: Yes, I rebooted the server completely.